# SharePoint 2013 issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013

When clicking on the logo of my site it does not return me to the homepage of the site.  I have no way of returning after clicking a link to another page.  Any suggestions?

Thank you,

-Matt

Comment: Here is something that should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582710/sharepoint-redirect-site-logo-link-to-the-root-site-collection-home-page

Answer (score 2):

That is by design in all SharePoint editions. By default the logo link returns you the landing page of the current site you are on, whether it's the root or a subsite.

If you want to change this behavior you'll have to open up your site in SharePoint Designer, open your masterpage and in it find ID `"onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic"`. This control should have a property called `NavigateUrl`. Change its value from `~site/` to `~sitecollection/`. Save, check in, and publish and your logo should now return you to the homepage when clicked.